# Complete English translation of Kumārila Bhaṭṭa's Tantravārttika

Tags: translation-request, purva-mimamsa, kumarila-bhatta

In his [two volume work](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/kumarila-bhatta-tantravarttika-commentary-on-sabara-s-bhasya-on-purvamimamsa-sutras-of-jaimini-fascicles-i-ix-in-two-volumes-IDJ139/), Ganganath Jha appears to have only translated the [first three chapters](https://archive.org/details/tantravartikacom00kumr/page/n1787) (out of the total twelve listed below) of Kumārila Bhaṭṭa's Tantravārttika. Has any other scholar translated the Tantravārttika in full? Is it available online for free or purchase?

> [Mimamsa Sutra consists of twelve chapters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purva_Mimamsa_Sutras#Content):
>
> 1. In the first chapter import of the collections of words which have various meanings is discussed. Such as, injunction (vidhi),
>      explanatory passage (arthavada), hymn (mantra), tradition (smriti)
>      etc.
> 2. In the second chapter, discussions relating to the difference of various rites, refutation of erroneously proofs etc. are held.
> 3. In the third chapter, sruti, sense of the passage (linga), context (vakya), and their respective weight when in apparent opposition to
>      one another, the ceremonies called pratipatti-karmani, things
>      mentioned incidentally (anarabhyadhita) and the duties of the
>      sacrifices are expounded.
> 4. In the fourth chapter, the influence on other rites of the principal and subordinate rites, the fruit caused by the juhu and
>      dice-playing, which forms a subordinate part of the rajasuya sacrifice
>      are explained.
> 5. Fifth chapter discusses relative order of various passages of sruti, different parts of sacrifice etc.
> 6. In the sixth chapter, the persons qualified to offer sacrifices, their obligations, the substitutes for materials used in sacrifices,
>      expiatory rites and the different sacrificial fires are made clear.
>
> 7-8. In the seventh and eight chapters, transference of ceremonies and transference by virtue from one sacrifice to another are discussed.
>
> 9. In the ninth chapter, adaptation of hymns when quoted in a new context (uha), and melodies (samans) and mantras are discussed.
> 10. In the tenth, the discussion revolves around the non-performance of the primary rites and dependent rites, offerings to grahas, etc.
> 11. In the eleventh chapter, there is discussion on tantra (combining several acts one), and avapa (performance of an act more than once).
> 12. In the twelfth chapter, prasanga, tantra and cumulation of concurrent rites (samuchchaya) is explained.

Comment: Those are indeed 12 Adhyayas of Jaimini’s Purva Mimamsa Sutras, but the Tantra Vartika does not cover all those Adhyayas.  Kumarila Bhatta’s Shloka Vartika covers Adhyaya 1 Pada 1, his Tantra Vartika covers the Adhyaya 1 Padas 2-4 along with Adhyayas 2 and 3, and his Tuptika covers Adhyayas 4-12.  The Shloka Vartika and Tantra Vartika have been translated into English, but the Tuptika hasn’t been translated.

Comment: By the way, Kumarila Bhatta’s three works are all subcommentaries on (different parts) of Shabara’s Bhashya, which itself is a commentary on Jaimini’s Purva Mimamsa Sutras.  Shabara’s Bhashya on all 12 Adhyayas is available in English, if you’re interested in that.

Comment: You're right. I thought Tuptika was an unrelated work of Kumarila. But that's exactly what I was looking for. @KeshavSrinivasan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are really looking for is the translation of [Ṭupṭīkā](https://archive.org/details/tuptikak00kuma/page/n5) which has not been translated to English yet.

From the [Introduction to English translation of Ślokavārtika](https://archive.org/stream/slokavartika015341mbp#page/n23/mode/2up) by Ganganath Jha:

> On the Bhāṣya [of Śabara], we have the commentary of Kumārila Bhaṭṭa, generally 
>   spoken of as "Bhatta." This work is divided into three parts, known 
>   under three different names:
>
> 1. The Ślokavārtika, treating of the  first, the Tarka, (Polemical) Pāda of the First Adhyāya (published in  the 'Caukhambhā Sanskrit
>      Series,' Benares);
> 2. The Tantravārtika, dealing with the last three Pādas of Adhyāya I, and the whole of  Adhyāya II and III (published in the 'Benares
>      Sanskrit Series,' and being translated into English by the present
>      translator);–and
> 3. The **Ṭupṭīkā dealing with Adhyayas IV-XII** (published in the 'Benares Sanskrit Series').